# PrestShop: Import from XLS?

Tags: php, prestashop

Is there a possibility to import XLS Files into Prestashop? I would imagine myself a Script where I define which rows (as an Example A1-A300 should be Names of the articles, etc...) are what (Like name, price, Tax, etc...).

How could I realise that? I hope there is a possibility and I would appreciate if anyone could get ma on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrestaShop doesn't support excel files, only simple data tables like `.csv`. This is because excel files are too complicated, they can by whole programs by themselves.

However, if you're working for a client or your XLS files are just simple data, then surely you can convert XLS to CSV before import.

You just need to make an override for `AdminImportController::ajaxProcessUploadCSV`

and basically "intercept file upload". Get the uploaded file and convert it to CSV using this library:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Then just return are the right values in your override to simulate that "everything is running normal" (basically trick PrestaShop :)) .

It is definitely doable, I've created such module for a client, PHPExcel gave us the ability to work with cells before saving them to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import products form Excel without converting to CSV, there is extension, Store Manager for PrestaShop - https://www.prestashopmanager.com/free-download/

It is paid, but you can do the task with 2-week version without any fees.